# Lifting action of torus to torus bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, fibre-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

**Preamble:** Let $X$ be a simply connected smooth manifold and $P \to X$ be a principal $T^\ell$ bundle on it.
Let $\phi$ be a smooth action of $T^k$ on $X$.

The paper "[Lifting compact group actions in fiber bundles](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/math1924/2/1/2_1_13/_pdf)" by Hattori and Yoshida suggests that the following is true:

> **Theorem:** Let $X$ be a simply connected manifold and $P \to X$ be a $T^\ell$-principal bundle.
>
> Then any $T^k$ smooth action on $X$ lifts to an action on $P$.
> Moreover there is a bijective correspondence between the lifts of a given action up to conjugation by elements of $\mathrm{Aut}(P)$ and elements of $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^k, \mathbb{Z}^\ell)$.

Above I say suggests because technically this result is not stated in the smooth case, but I am willing to believe it holds in the smooth case.

**Question:** As I am not very familiar with the algebraic topology involved in the paper, I was hoping that someone could explain to me, in a differential geometry language, how do I write down explicitly all the lifts of a torus action.

**Motivation:** My ultimate goal is, given a principal connection $\theta \in \Omega^1(P; \mathbb{R}^\ell) = (\Omega^1(P))^\ell$ on $P \to X$ whose curvature $d\theta$ is preserved by $\phi$, to check whether there exists a lift of $\phi$ to $P$ that preserves $\theta$ (as in $\mathcal{L}_\xi(\theta) = 0 $ for any fundamental vector field of the lift of $\phi$).
Note that we made an identification $\mathrm{Lie}(T^\ell) \cong \mathbb{R}^\ell$, which defines $\ell$ fundamental vector fields $W_i$ for the principal action of $T^\ell$ that span the vertical space of $P \to M$ at each point.
In terms of these, I can write the fundamental vector fields $\xi_j$ of a lifted action of $T^k$ as
$$
    \xi_j = \xi^H_j + \sum_i a_i W_i
$$
where $\xi^H_j$ are the horizontal component with respect to $\theta$ and $a_i \in C^\infty(P)$.
With this notation the equation $\mathcal{L}_{\xi_j}(\theta_i) = 0$ reads $da_i + \xi_j^H \lrcorner d \theta_i = 0$.
I am trying to find some conditions under which one of the lifts mentioned by Hattori and Yoshida satisfies these equations.

Comment: The action on the fiber is given by a group homomorphism $T^k\to T^{\ell}$, which comes from a homomorphism of the corresponding lattices $\mathbb{Z}^k\to\mathbb{Z}^{\ell}$. Then, given a smooth manifold $X$ with $T^k\curvearrowright X$, for each coordinate chart $U$, we can lift the action of $T^k$ on $U$ to $U\times T^{\ell}$ by the diagonal action, and then glue them together. There're some obstructions appearing, but I think it's removed by the simply connectedness condition.

Comment: @TheWildCat Unless the bundle is trivial, is this choice of group homomorphism global though? I mean can we glue e.g. the action relative to the trivial morphism $T^k \to T^\ell$ for a nontrivial bundle? I thought this classification would have been more something that involved choosing a preferred lift and writing the others in terms of that one

Comment: For your motivational problem, note that for $l=1$ and the curvature on the base being non-degenerate, this is a classical problem in symplectic geometry. In this case, infinitesimal lifts of the action correspond to infinitesimal equivariant momentum maps (i.e. you want to choose the $a_i$'s in such a way that you do get an Lie algebra action). So, in particular, unless your action on the base is Hamiltonian you don't get such a nice lift. This you also directly see from your last equation: just project it down on the base

Comment: @TobiasDiez thanks for this! I was aware that my question was related to symplectic geometry, yet I did not find much when I searched. Do you have any specific reference in mind?

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantomorphism+group#group_extension and references therein (Kostant and Brylinski)